# Replace a provider object during runtime

Tags: nestjs

Let's say I have a module that provides a connection to something.

```
export const CONN string = 'CONN';

@Global()
@Module({})
export class ConnModule implements OnApplicationShutdown {
  constructor(@Inject(CONN) private readonly conn: Connection) {}

  onApplicationShutdown() {
    this.conn.close();
  }

  static forRoot(options): DynamicModule {
    const connectionProvider = {
      provide: CONN,
      useFactory: async (): Promise<Connection> => {
        const connection = new Connection(options);
        await connection.establish();
        return connection;
      },
    };

    return {
      module: ConnModule ,
      providers: [connectionProvider],
      exports: [connectionProvider],
    };
  }
}
```

This connection is used through the application:

```
export class AService {
  constructor(
    @Inject(CONN) protected readonly conn: Connection,
  ) {}

  someMethod() {
    this.conn.doSomething(); // this may get 401ed
  }

export class BService {
  constructor(
    @Inject(CONN) protected readonly conn: Connection,
  ) {}

  otherMethod() {
    this.conn.doSomethingElse(); // this may get 401ed
  }
```

This is a connection to 3rd party app and it may start returning 401 anytime needing us to reauthenticate / recreate a connection.

How can I create a new connection on error and replace the current provider for all the modules that are using it?

Something like:

```
OnConnectionUnauthorizedException ->
create a new Connection ->
replace the current stale connection object that CONN provides with a new one ->
retry the original action
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This sounds concerning to me. As it is hard to communicate to the outside what the status of your application is. Also, what will happen to processing events/requests during the time of the connection re-establishing? You are going to handle a lot of accidental complexity. Consider health checks at least to expose your application's status.

Yet there is a solution that I can imagine: Instead of providing the connection, provide a service that holds the connection in a private field. Make a `getConection` method, possibly async to gap disconnected times, and return the connection. This way you don't have to replace the injected value.

I would furthermore really discourage replacing an injected value. As this is really hard to communicate to code that might be dependent on this value. ("e.g. hey here is a new instance).

```
export class ConnectionService {
  connection: Conection | undefined;

  // Pro Tip: make getConnection async and leverage e.g. Promise.race to implement
  // a timeout so that if the connection is down this code e.g. delays 5 seconds and 
  // if the connection gets re-established, answers with the new connection or throws 
  // a "Couldnt reconnect" error
  getConnection(){
    return this.connection;
  }
}
```

**This solution should be your last resort and instead, you should challenge the source of the required reconnect.**